# Yii's captcha doesn't show up, unless remove the accessControl

Tags: php, yii

Only when I remove the filters() method, the captcha can show up. other time the captcha doesn't work. and my php gd support is enable.
by the way, if I access test/captcha directly, it only show a picture box, but not content, maybe can not load the picture..

Here is my TestController.php

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->render('index');
}

public function actions()
{
    return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
            'minLength' => 4,
            'maxLength' => 4,
            'testLimit' => 99999
            )
    );
}


public function filters()
{
    // return the filter configuration for this controller, e.g.:
    return array(
        "accessControl",
    );
}

public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('captcha','index'),
            'users'=>array('*')
        )
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 1 to many arrays in accessRules(). Should be...

```
public function accessRules() {
    return array('allow', 
          'actions' => array('captcha'),
          'users' => array('*')
    );
}
```